# Displacy Custom Colors for custom entities using Displacy

Tags: python, spacy

I have a list of words, noun-verb phrases and I want to:

- Search dependency patterns, words, in a corpus of text
- identify the paragraph that matches appears in
- extract the paragraph
- highlight the matched words in the paragraph
- create a snip/jpeg of the paragraph with matched words highlighted
- save the image in an excel.

The MWE below pertains to highlighting the matched words and displaying them using displacy. I have mentioned the rest of my task just to provide the context. The output isn't coloring the custom entities with custom colors.

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
from spacy.tokens import Span

good = ['bacon', 'chicken', 'lamb','hot dog']
bad = [ 'apple', 'carrot']

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')  
patterns1 = [nlp(good) for good in good]
patterns2 = [nlp(bad) for bad in bad]
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add('good', None, *patterns1)
matcher.add('bad', None, *patterns2)

doc = nlp("I like bacon and chicken but unfortunately I only had an apple and a carrot in the fridge")
matches = matcher(doc)

for match_id, start, end in matches:
    
    span = Span(doc, start, end, label=match_id)
    doc.ents = list(doc.ents) + [span]  # add span to doc.ents

print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])
```

The code above produces this output:

```
[('bacon', 'good'), ('chicken', 'good'), ('apple', 'bad'), ('carrot', 'bad')]
```

But when I try to custom color the entities, it doesn't seem to be working.

```
from spacy import displacy
colors = {'good': "#85C1E9", "bad": "#ff6961"}
options = {"ents": ['good', 'bad'], "colors": colors}

displacy.serve(doc, style='ent',options=options)
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

Comment: Please note your spaCy version.

Comment: @polm23 My Spacy version is 2.3.5

Comment: Can you upgrade spaCy? That's probably the easiest option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just copy/pasted your code and it works fine here. I'm using spaCy v3.1.1.

[image]

What does the HTML output source look like?

---

I was able to reproduce your issue on spaCy 2.3.5. I was able to fix it by making the labels upper-case (GOOD and BAD). I can't find a bug about this but since the models normally only use uppercase labels I guess this is an issue with older versions.

Comment: How can I see the HTML output source? I'm sorry i don't know what that means actually.

Comment: You can use right click -> select "inspect". In Chrome it might be F12 or ctrl+shift+i.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Googlers, the answer is:  store some colours e.g. [the default colours from Spacy](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/displacy/render.py#L17-L36) `colors = {'your_class1': "#85C1E9", "your_class2": "#ff6961", ... }` and set `options = {"ents": list(colors), "colors": colors}` then run `displacy.render(doc, style='ent', options=options)`

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing my own, quite customized, example which uses SpaCy to visualize FrameNet annotations:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('framenet_v17')
from nltk.corpus import framenet as fn
from spacy import displacy
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

FRAME_NAME = "Expectation" # choice your own from fn.frames() !
FRAME_ELEMENTS = [e.name for _,e in fn.frame_by_name(FRAME_NAME)['FE'].items() if e['coreType'] == 'Core']
print(f"Frame={FRAME_NAME},CoreElements={'+'.join(FRAME_ELEMENTS)}")

COLORS = plt.cycler("color", plt.cm.Pastel2.colors) # chose your colors !
COLORS = [matplotlib.colors.to_hex(c['color']) for c in COLORS] # doesn't work work in RGB? 
COLORS = dict(zip([FRAME_NAME]+FRAME_ELEMENTS,COLORS))

for s in fn.exemplars(frame='Expectation'):

    span_labels = [dict(s)['Target'][0]+(FRAME_NAME,)]+dict(s)['FE'][0]
    span_labels = [{"start":t[0],"end":t[1],"label":t[2]} for t in span_labels]

    args = {
        "text": s['text'],
        "ents": span_labels,
    }

    displacy.render(args,style="ent",manual=True,options={"colors":COLORS})
```

[image]